# com.liferay.portlet.asset.AssetCategoryException

Tags: jsf, liferay

I am getting the following error while adding document/links.

```
com.liferay.portlet.asset.AssetCategoryException
        at com.liferay.portlet.asset.util.BaseAssetEntryValidator.validate(BaseAssetEntryValidator.java:136)
        at com.liferay.portlet.asset.util.BaseAssetEntryValidator.validate(BaseAssetEntryValidator.java:75)
        at com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.impl.AssetEntryLocalServiceImpl.validate(AssetEntryLocalServiceImpl.java:927)
        at com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.impl.AssetEntryLocalServiceImpl.updateEntry(AssetEntryLocalServiceImpl.java:582)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2598.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy312.updateEntry(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLAppHelperLocalServiceImpl.updateAsset(DLAppHelperLocalServiceImpl.java:1262)
        at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLAppHelperLocalServiceImpl.addFileEntry(DLAppHelperLocalServiceImpl.java:102)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy416.addFileEntry(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLAppServiceImpl.addFileEntry(DLAppServiceImpl.java:305)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy415.addFileEntry(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLAppServiceUtil.addFileEntry(DLAppServiceUtil.java:196)
        at com.eteam.bpa.view.MyFilesAddView.saveMyFiles(MyFilesAddView.java:218)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:329)
        at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:274)
        at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.getValue(AstMethodSuffix.java:59)
        at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.invoke(AstMethodSuffix.java:65)
        at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
        at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
        at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseActionImpl.execute(BridgePhaseActionImpl.java:81)
        at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:86)
        at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.processAction(GenericFacesPortlet.java:152)
        at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:71)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:583)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:628)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:308)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doProcessAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:402)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.processAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:110)
        at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.processAction(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2924.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedHandler$InvokePrivilegedExceptionAction.run(DoPrivilegedHandler.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedHandler.doInvoke(DoPrivilegedHandler.java:100)
        at com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedHandler.invoke(DoPrivilegedHandler.java:56)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.processAction(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.processAction(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:75)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.processAction(PortletContainerUtil.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:378)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.doExecute(LayoutAction.java:200)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:95)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:178)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:549)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:526)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:156)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:359)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:243)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:267)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:226)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invokeer.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at it.sella.realm.servlet.TokenIdentityAssertionFilter$AuthenticatedFilterChain$1.run(TokenIdentityAssertionFilter.java:130)
        at it.sella.realm.servlet.TokenIdentityAssertionFilter$AuthenticatedFilterChain$1.run(TokenIdentityAssertionFilter.java:122)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at it.sella.realm.servlet.TokenIdentityAssertionFilter$AuthenticatedFilterChain.doAsSubject(TokenIdentityAssertionFilter.java:149)
        at it.sella.realm.servlet.TokenIdentityAssertionFilter$AuthenticatedFilterChain.doFilter(TokenIdentityAssertionFilter.java:122)
        at it.sella.realm.servlet.TokenIdentityAssertionFilter.doFilter(TokenIdentityAssertionFilter.java:85)
        at it.sella.ssoclient.fe.IdentityAssertionFilter.doFilter(IdentityAssertionFilter.java:30)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
11:03:22,465 DEBUG [DebugPhaseListener:48] AFTER phaseId=[INVOKE_APPLICATION 5] viewId=[/views/carica-file-addfiles/view.xhtml]
11:03:22,622 DEBUG [DebugPhaseListener:64] BEFORE phaseId=[RESTORE_VIEW 1] viewId=[null]
11:03:22,628 DEBUG [DebugPhaseListener:64] BEFORE phaseId=[RESTORE_VIEW 1] viewId=[null]
11:03:22,622 DEBUG [DebugPhaseListener:64] BEFORE phaseId=[RESTORE_VIEW 1] viewId=[null]
11:03:22,634 DEBUG [DebugPhaseListener:48] AFTER phaseId=[RESTORE_VIEW 1] viewId=[/views/i-miei-files-jsf/view.xhtml]
11:03:22,634 DEBUG [DebugPhaseListener:48] AFTER phaseId=[RESTORE_VIEW 1] viewId=[/views/procedure-slider/view.xhtml]
11:03:22,635 DEBUG [DebugPhaseListener:48] AFTER phaseId=[RESTORE_VIEW 1] viewId=[/views/related-user/view.xhtml]
```

My code is as follows.

```
LiferayFacesContext liferayFacesContext = LiferayFacesContext.getInstance();
                ServiceContext serviceContext = liferayFacesContext.getServiceContext();
                FileEntry FileEntry= DLAppServiceUtil.addFileEntry( 
                        themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), dlFolderIdInSession, 
                        uploadedFile.getFileName(), 
                        uploadedFile.getContentType(), myFileName, "", "", 
                        uploadedFile.getInputstream(), 
                        uploadedFile.getSize(), serviceContext);
```

please help.

Jobin Mathew

Answer (score 1):

From Liferay control panel,
Go to Sites->Content->categories
open Associated Asset Types.
Then uncheck the "Required" checkbox.